# How to see UITableViewDataSource protocol in swift 3?

Tags: uitableview, swift3

How can I view the UITableViewDataSource protocol that is currently used by the Swift compiler? I'm guessing it is in a file somewhere that the compiler reads. How can I see that file?

I'm getting the error "Type ... does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'" but there is no hint about why it is nonconformant. An earlier version of the app in Swift 2 didn't have this error so i'm guessing it arose because of the Swift 3 renaming. I know the protocol requires at least numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath and I have both. I probably have an argument spelling or return type wrong or something like that.

The current (and recent) API documentation drives me crazy! So many details seem to be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol reference is here:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource

You should also be able to press CMD + Shift + O and type in UITableViewDataSource to jump to the header from inside your project:

[image: Open Quickly Shortcut]

Comment: That's a great find. I'm surprised that somehow I didn't know about cmd-shift-O. I knew about cmd-shift-0 (number zero) to go to documentation but that isn't the same documentation. I notice that (I think) when I do cmd-shift-O in a Swift file I get swift interface documentation and when I do it in an objC file I get objC interface documentation.